# CSS child selector that don't count some div at all

Tags: html, css

I just have some child div with a some class, in this case .element. And first one with some other class, in this case .skip. I need to don't count that element, like it doesn't exist. So if i take every odd div with .element class to take same divs even if .skip div is there or deleted. If it possible with some css selector like you can with .nth-of-type if that .skip element isn't a div, or somehow just with css to make it hidden to nth selector.

It's important not to use javascript.

```html
<div>
<div class="skip">no</div>
<div class="element">1</div>
<div class="element">2</div>
<div class="element">3</div>
<div class="element">4</div>
<div class="element">5</div>
<div class="element">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `nth-of-class` selector (yet), so you'd have to use JavaScript. There are lots of duplicates of this question here, so look around for a few solutions

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need to work in some buggy cms system and in development mode, I had some empty div, but in production, it is removed. And this shit cms doesn't take javascript at all.

Comment: When it is present, is the `.skip` element always before the `.element` elements?

Comment: Always is before, but in some case .skip is there and in some case isn't. But it always is first one.

Answer (score 0):

simply ignore the skip div and take only odd values of element divs like so:

```css
div.element:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ibrahim-abboud/pen/JjaNVPR

Comment: In some case that div will not be there and in some case it will be. So this isn't a option.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use different HTML tags for the elements mentioned, you could still define a `nth-of-child` selector. For instance, adding strikethrough to all odd elements with `element` class

```css
div.element:nth-of-type(odd) {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="skip">no</span>
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <div class="element">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is because I can't change html at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It reads the following way: "If there is a .element element that's preceded by a .skip element, when the .element element is in an even position do whatever css rules establish". You will need to switch selections -> odd becomes even and even becomes odd (in your case, odd numbers are in even positions). I've added a color change to make it obvious. Switching it to odd will select 2,4,6 etc.

```css
.skip ~ .element:nth-of-type(even) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="skip">no</div>
<div class="element">1</div>
<div class="element">2</div>
<div class="element">3</div>
<div class="element">4</div>
<div class="element">5</div>
<div class="element">6</div>
</div>
```